# ruby Datamapper: Get next record from a collection

Tags: ruby, datamapper

How can I get the next record from a collection while looping through a collection? eg.

```
for record in collection
  current_value = record.value
  next_value    = record.next.value #==> Would like this!
  # more stuff with record
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like that:

```
collection.each_with_index do |record, index|
  current_value = record.value
  next_value    = collection[index+1].value
  # more stuff
end
```

Comment: The last item in the collection will break this code. Of course, this was the case in the original question too, but anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons) (`DataMapper::Collection` includes `Enumerable`):

```ruby
collection.each_cons(2) do |a|
  #here a is a 2 element array:
  current_value = a[0]
  next_value    = a[1] #(or just use the array elements directly)

end
```

using `each_cons` means you don't have to worry about checking for the last element in the collection.

There's also the similar [`each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), which yields non-overlapping groups from the collection.

Comment: This works well. However, the last element in the collection is never assigned to `a[0]`.